# Matching in Artificial intelligence, unification

Tags: regex, artificial-intelligence, matching, unification

trying to implement matching which is a limited form
of unification.

trying to match two formulas match if we can find substitutions for
the variables appearing in the formulas such that the two are syntactically
equivalent.

I need to write a  function that determines whether a
constant corresponding to a ground term such as Brother(George) and a
pattern corresponding to a quantified formula such as Brother(x) match. If
they do match the function returns a set of substitutions called bindings
that map variables to terms. A constant matches another constant if they
are equal. An unbound variable (one currently without a binding) matches
any formula. A bound variable matches a constant if the constant and the
value to which the variable is bound are equal.

examples:

> match( Loves(Dog(Fred), Fred)
>
> Loves(x,y))
>
> is true with x = Dog(Fred) and y = Fred

another one

> match( Loves(Dog(Fred), Fred)
>
> Loves(x,x)
>
> fails

Comment: Why don't you use prolog? It comes with the unification for free

Comment: Implement as a regex? In what language? Sed? Perl? Grep? Unfortunately for us, there are different flavors of regex.

Comment: trying to do in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of MGUs i.e. **Most General Unifiers** seems to be of use over here. The solution methodology is illustrated below.
Let us have an initial empty set named **mgu** and another empty set **E**.

```
mgu = {}
G = match(Loves(Dog(Fred),Fred),Loves(x,y))
E = {Loves(Dog(Fred),Fred),Loves(x,y)}


mgu = {Fred|y}             // Replace Fred by y, variables to be replaced first.
G = match(Loves(Dog(y),y),Loves(x,y))
E = {Loves(Dog(y),y),Loves(x,y)}


mgu = {Fred|y,Dog(y)|x}    // Replace Dog(y) by x
G = match(Loves(x,y),Loves(x,y))  
E = {Loves(x,y)}           // E becomes a singleton set here, we stop here.
                           // No more substitutions are possible at this stage.
```

**match()** returns **True** if **E** becomes a singleton set when no more substitutions are possible, otherwise **False**. And the **mgu** can be returned as the set of substitutions required.

```
G = True
mgu = {Fred|y,Dog(y)|x}
```

The other example can be illustrated as follows.

```
mgu = {}
G = match(Loves(Dog(Fred),Fred),Loves(x,x))
E = {Loves(Dog(Fred),Fred),Loves(x,x)}


mgu = {Fred|x}             // Replace Fred by x.
G = match(Loves(Dog(x),x),Loves(x,x))
E = {Loves(Dog(x),x),Loves(x,x)}


mgu = {Fred|x,Dog(x)|y}       // Replace Dog(x) by y
G = match(Loves(y,x),Loves(x,x))  
E = {Loves(y,x),Loves(x,x)}   // E does not becomes a singleton set here.
                              // But no more substitutions are 
                              // possible at this stage.
```

Therefore,

```
G = False
```

Comment: can you help me parsing them in Python ? I know prolog is easy to do that, 
so in Python I would need to split by comma but what if there is more than a comma ?